# QQmlEngine and cmake

Tags: c++, qml

I have trouble including **QQmlEngine** into a **cmake** project.

Here is my C++:

```
#include <QtQml/QQmlEngine>
...
QObject *someQObject;
QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(someQObject, QQmlEngine::ObjectOwnership::CppOwnership);
```

And the cmake part:

```
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Qml REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Quick REQUIRED)
...
add_executable(name ${src})
qt5_use_modules(name Core Gui Qml Quick )
```

Compilation fails with:

```
CMakeFiles/....cpp.o: In function `...':
....cpp:57: undefined reference to `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(QObject*, QQmlEngine::ObjectOwnership)'
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I missing?

**Edit, @qCring (Sorry, can't comment your answer):**

Well, everything works fine when I leave out the "setObjectOwnership" call. The rest of the Qt application works fine. Thus it is actually linking somehow.

When I add your line I get

```
"The plain signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with the target "name".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a target   must be either all-keyword or all-plain."
```

**Edit:**

My problem vanished somehow. I am running arch linux on x86_64.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you provide some more information about your system and the versions of Qt and CMake you use? Also worth a try: you could check out [this CMake project template](https://github.com/qCring/QMLApplicationTemplate) to see if the error still occurs when you call `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership`. Then we can figure out if it's a CMake or Qt issue.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually linked to the Qt libraries and therefore get undefined symbol errors. Both macros, `find_package` and `qt5_use_modules` just provide CMake variables from certain packages/modules. You have to link the libraries like this:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Qt5::Core PUBLIC Qt5::Gui PUBLIC Qt5::Quick PUBLIC Qt5::Qml)
```